# Custom color for fence, whisker and outliers in BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

How can I use custom color for fence, whisker and outliers.

Here is my MWE

```
 col = {Red, Darker@Green, Blue, Orange}; SeedRandom@5;
    data = Table[
       RandomReal[BetaDistribution[\[Alpha], 1.5], 
        100], {\[Alpha], {6, 3, 7, 8}}];
    BoxWhiskerChart[data, {"Outliers", {"MedianMarker", White}}, 
     ChartStyle -> col]
```

[image]

What I want is this kind of chart.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a custom `ChartElementFunction` and pass the color information as metadata using `Thread[data->col]` as the first argument in `BoxWhiskerChart`:

```
ClearAll[cef]   

 cef = {EdgeForm[#3[[1]]], FaceForm[], 
    ChartElementData["BoxWhisker"][##] /. {l_Line :> {#3[[1]], l}, 
      GrayLevel[0] -> #3[[1]]}} &;
BoxWhiskerChart[
 Thread[data -> col], {"Outliers", {"MedianMarker", White}}, 
 ChartStyle -> col, ChartElementFunction -> cef]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[cef2] 
cef2 = {EdgeForm[#3[[1]]], FaceForm[#3[[1]]], 
    ChartElementData[
       "BoxWhisker"][##] /. {GrayLevel[0 | .5] -> #3[[1]]}} &;
BoxWhiskerChart[
 Thread[data -> col], {"Outliers", {"MedianMarker", White}}, 
 ChartStyle -> col, ChartElementFunction -> cef2]
```

[image]